# Alternatives : Odespy for Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: package-management, python, python3, programming, 20.10

I am interested in numerical methods for solving odes using Python. I would like to refere to:

> *Linge, S., & Langtangen, H. P. (2020). Programming for Computations-Python: A Gentle Introduction to Numerical Simulations
> with Python 3.6 (p. 332). Springer Nature*.

In this book **[Odespy](https://github.com/hplgit/odespy)** package has been considered as a milestone for numerical integration of odes (and systems of).

I know that using Odespy with my Ubuntu is **not possible because of my Ubuntu version**.

Unfortunately I have the last version of Ubuntu i.e. 20.10 which doesn't support odespy (e.g. [see here](https://repology.org/project/python:odespy/versions)).
This kind of package is written for Python 2.7 and I have Python 3.

Is there a valid **alternative** to this package?

Comment: An option is to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 20.04 LTS somewhere (VM, Docker, schroot) with its python 2 and then use odespy inside it. Better way is to remove installed 20.10 and install 20.04 LTS instead on the same drive. This will give 5 years of support and prevent frequent release upgrades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) integrate for odes integration.
Anyway, for rigourous applications, I recommend a handiwork integrator in which you set the timestep.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Is this an answer? Has it solved your issue? If not, please add this as extra information to your question instead.

Comment: this is what you pay as a linux freshman

Answer (score 1):

This software may be installed on 20.10, but you need to manually get NumPy for Python 2 from 20.04 LTS repository; SciPy from 18.04 LTS. Use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev gfortran-9 git

# set gfortran-9 as default (as in 20.04 LTS)
sudo apt-get remove gfortran # remove gfortran-10
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gfortran-9 /usr/local/bin/gfortran

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-numpy/python-numpy_1.16.5-2ubuntu7_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-numpy_1.16.5-2ubuntu7_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-scipy/python-scipy_0.19.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-scipy_0.19.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb

git clone https://github.com/hplgit/odespy
cd odespy
sudo python2 setup.py install
```

And then use `odespy`.